# loaderlock MDA - later in the application execution

Tags: c#, interop

Here's the problem I have when running my app, and it isn't in any startup routing, but much later on:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'LoaderLock' has detected a problem in 'C:\Projects\VideoPhill\PlayerRAC\Recorder\VidePhill Recorder Test\bin\x86\Debug\VideoPhillRecorder.vshost.exe'.
>   Additional Information: DLL 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC\Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound\1.0.2902.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound.dll' is attempting managed execution inside OS Loader lock. Do not attempt to run managed code inside a DllMain or image initialization function since doing so can cause the application to hang.

Why?  Where to look?  I causes me problem while debuging, not in the runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That MDA has a knack for giving false warnings.  Clearly the CLR is already loaded and initialized by the time the DirectX wrappers are getting loaded, your program doesn't actually hang.  Debug + Exceptions, expand the Managed Debugging Assistants node and untick "LoaderLock" so it stops nagging you.

Do avoid expending a lot of energy on MDX, it has been declared obsolete quite a while ago.  Replaced by the XNA Framework.  There are some open source wrappers floating around too (SlimDX, SharpDX, DirectShow.NET).  I can't comment on their prowess.

Comment: I'm all into the DirectShow.NET and loving it.  MDX?  Don't even know what it is :)

Comment: MDX = Managed DirectX, what you are using.

Comment: Yeah - really - I am combining lots of stuff inside - this functionality wasn't wrapped in DirectShow.NET...